# What are the tax liabilities for an international transaction?

Tags: united-kingdom, canada, taxes, vat, ecommerce

I have website for which I have set up a sponsorship scheme for (see my profile if you're interested). With this scheme, some individual or company can choose to sponsor X or Y amount and that gives them an advertising block on my website for Z months.

I have had an inquiry for sponsorship of the site, which is nice. However the question came up over the tax implications for the transaction, so I thought I'd ask it here.

Goods and services sold in the UK are currently subject to 15% VAT. If the purchaser is based outside the UK (in this case Canada), how does it work?

- Do I still charge the VAT and the customer claims it back from their local tax office?
- Do I charge without VAT and the customer is liable?
- Some other option?

Does the situation change depending on the countries involved, or is it covered by some international law?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of rooting around the HMRC sites, I found [this page](http://www.businesslink.gov.uk/bdotg/action/detail?r.s=sl&r.lc=en&type=RESOURCES&itemId=1074412033) which says this:

> One key difference is that digitised products are classed as electronically-supplied services for VAT and customs duties. These services are:
>
> - downloaded software
> - downloaded images, text or information
> - electronic publications
> - downloaded music, films and games
> - electronic auctions
> - supply of websites or web-hosting services
>
> For VAT purposes, the place of supply of these services is the country in which the customer lives.
>
> If you supply electronic services to a business customer in another European Union (EU) country, the customer accounts for any VAT due in that country. You should not charge UK VAT.
>
> If you supply electronic services to a consumer, charity or government body in another EU country, you have to account for UK VAT.
>
> If you supply electronic services to anyone in a country outside the EU, you don't pay any VAT.
>
> If, as a UK business, you buy electronic services from a company outside the UK, you have to account for VAT.

If I read this correctly, I as the supplier of the website need to account for VAT only if the sponsor is a consumer, charity or government body in another EU country.

It is not covered in this site, but I assume I must also account for VAT for a customer based in the UK.

---

So in answer to the original question, a customer from Canada (which is currently outside the EU) would account for the VAT themselves, and I would simply charge the gross amount.

Comment: So that means that the supplier is exempt from the VAT but does that mean that Canadian consumer must still remit VAT to the U.K.?